# An extra Invoke of kernel's Compute method

Tags: tensorflow

Build a naive kernel like below.

```cpp
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"                                                                                                                                                      
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"                                                                                                                                               
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"                                                                                                                                                  
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/core/errors.h"                                                                                                                                                   
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/core/status.h"                                                                                                                                                   
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/strings/str_util.h"                                                                                                                                              
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/strings/strcat.h"                                                                                                                                                
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"                                                                                                                                         
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/logging.h"                                                                                                                                                  


namespace tensorflow {                                                                                                                                                                         

using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                                           

REGISTER_OP("Test")                                                                                                                                                                            
.Input("in: int32")                                                                                                                                                                            
.Output("out: int32")                                                                                                                                                                          
// .SetIsStateful()                                                                                                                                                                            
.Doc(R"doc(                                                                                                                                                                                    
wierd                                                                                                                                                                                          
)doc");                                                                                                                                                                                        

class TestOp : public OpKernel {                                                                                                                                                               
 public:                                                                                                                                                                                       
  explicit TestOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                                                            

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {                                                                                                                                            
    LOG(INFO) << "Compute";                                                                                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                                                                                            
};                                                                                                                                                                                             

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("Test").Device(DEVICE_CPU), TestOp);                                                                                                                              

}  // namespace tensorflow
```

Run in python with:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
t = tf.load_op_library("./test_op.so")
test = t.test(8)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(test)
```

This prints "Compute" twice.

```sh
2017-07-21 15:34:23.049053: I test_op.cc:45] Compute
2017-07-21 15:34:23.049253: I test_op.cc:45] Compute
```

If `SetIsStateful` is turned on, or if the int "8" is replaced with a placeholder, it is then only executed once. 
Is this intentional? Why is it necessary?

Comment: Might not the case here, but note that runtime needs to be able to do "dummy runs" -- execute kernels for profiling purposes

Comment: You probably need to check the logging settings.